# Field Collection fields causes errors in array_flip functions in /includes/entity.inc

Tags: 7, entities

This is a follow up question from [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/253118/how-to-find-which-module-is-causing-php-warning). I now am sure that it's the Field Collection module that causes the error message `"Can only flip string and integer values!"`. My previous question was about HOW to find which module causes the error. I have now used Xdebug and Atom to backtrace the stack like this:

When the error arises on row 175 in /includes/entity.inc I have these values in the variable $ids:

```
$passed_ids = !empty($ids) ? array_flip($ids) : FALSE;
```

[image: entity.inc]

As you can see it's an array in an array, which causes the error, as array_flip() only can flip integers and strings, not arrays.

The array in an array value comes from row 8016 in /includes/common.inc:

```
function entity_load($entity_type, $ids = FALSE, $conditions = array(), $reset = FALSE) {
  if ($reset) {
    entity_get_controller($entity_type)->resetCache();
  }
  return entity_get_controller($entity_type)->load($ids, $conditions);
}
```

[image: common.inc]

Going one step further back in the stack, the value comes from these rows in sites/all/modules/entity/entity.module:

```
function entity_load_single($entity_type, $id) {
  $entities = entity_load($entity_type, array($id));
  return reset($entities);
}
```

[image: entity.module]

And if you bare with me, one more step back in the stack... to sites/all/modules/field_collection/field_collection_entity.inc, where I find these rows (row 265):

```
  public function hostEntity() {
    if ($this->fetchHostDetails()) {
      if (!isset($this->hostEntity) && $this->isInUse()) {
        $this->hostEntity = entity_load_single($this->hostEntityType, $this->hostEntityId);
      }
      elseif (!isset($this->hostEntity) && $this->hostEntityRevisionId) {
        $this->hostEntity = entity_revision_load($this->hostEntityType, $this->hostEntityRevisionId);
      }
      return $this->hostEntity;
    }
  }
```

[image]

Now to my question... what happens is that the `host entity id` (26391) is passed up the stack once for every field collection field that exists on the page. 10 field collection field instances = 10 error messages on row 175 in `/includes/entity.inc` (and equally many on row 388).

Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong? I suspect I have drawn this error upon myself. All other posts I have read among the issues for Field Collection suggests that this shouldn't be a problem any more. Otherwise I would have posted this in as an issue for Field Collection.

The field types I am using in these Field Collection fields are: Image, Long text and Link.

What more info can I give you to solve this problem? I am not an expert coder, so maybe there is something obvious in the stack above, that I don't see?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone has the same problem, try to update the module to the DEV version. In the above case the php error messages mentioned disappeared.